# Do we have to keep Exceptions serializable in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Since the concept of having multiple AppDomains is [going bye-bye](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#application-domains) in .NET 5, do we need to keep serializing custom Exceptions once the move is done? I understand that if I'm writing a library and it is consumed from .NET Framework, then the `Exception` needs to be `Serializable`, but barring that, is there a reason to, other than inertia?

Comment: Right, no need for that.

Comment: [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md). BinaryFormatter and SerializableAttribute will be removed soon.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I will trust it when I'll see it. Other than the breaking change .NET Framework -> .NET 5 I don't remember other "common" things that have been removed. `ArrayList` are still there watching us, together with the `ICollection.SyncRoot`/`ICollection.IsSynchronized`

Comment: @xanatos according to MS roadmap, `BinaryFormatter` will be removed completely in .NET 8 in 2023:)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski And in 2023 we will see if it will happen or if some very important clients will ask for a delay of another year or two, or if perhaps they'll simply move the obsolete classes in an assembly called `ObsoletedTypes.dll` and then they'll invent some strange mechanism to add post-mortem the `[Serializable]` attribute (that they want to remove)